# iOS - Is it considered bad practice to not mirror JSON perfectly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, swift, nsurlsession

For example, let’s say I have this json:

```
{
    "media": {
        "date": "2016-12-30",
        "uniqueID": "eab0923d"
}
```

I create an object from this json. But note that it contains another property to not make it mirror json 100%

```
class Media {
    var date: String?
    var uniqueID: String?
    var anotherProperty: String? // By adding this property, this object does not mirror json 100%

    init(jsonDictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.date = jsonDictionary["date"] as! String
        self.uniqueID = jsonDictionary["uniqueID"] as! String
        // Note: there is nothing in json for `anotherProperty`
    }
}
```

Is this good practice? If there are any potential dangers please let me know as well.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see any problem with that. As long as you know what you're doing.

Comment: Cool, does this happen often? And if so, do you see any potential dangers doing this? Thanks!

Comment: If you write a custom setter for media object that will always take care of anotherProperty's value, i think there will be no problem.

Comment: Why would I need a custom setter - can I just initialize this object with a `dictionary` from json, and then set the `anotherProperty` value however I want later? Srry for basic question. If you could provide example or link if easier to show that would be great

Comment: You could do that. But what if you forgot to set the value later? That might cause problem. If you have a setter function, then anotherProperty is ensured to be filled up correctly.

Comment: Right good point. So I updated my question so that my object contains an initializer. Notice how `anotherProperty` is not set. Could you please show an example of how to write a custom setter in this situation? thank you